# Flutter FutureProvider Execute build twice

Tags: flutter

I've changed from `Statefulwidget` using `initState` to fetch the data and `Futurebuilder` to load it to `Futureprovider`. But it seems like `Futureprovider` is execute `build`  method twice, while my previous approach executed it once. Is this behaviour normal?

```
class ReportsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ReportsPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureProvider<List<ReportModel>>(
      create: (_) async => ReportsProvider().loadReportData(1),
      initialData: null,
      catchError: (_, __) => null,
      child: const ReportWidg()
    );
  }
}

class ReportWidg extends StatelessWidget {
  const ReportWidg();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Execute Build");
    final reportList = Provider.of<List<ReportModel>>(context);
    if (reportList == null) {
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    } else if (reportList.isEmpty) {
      return Center(child: Text("Det finns inga rapporter."));
    }

    print(reportList.length);
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im relativly new to flutter but I think its because `StatelessWidget` is `@immutable`, which means whenever something changes it needs to rebuild itself.

At first build there is `async` calling made and `ReportWidg()` is rendered.

Then this line `final reportList = Provider.of<List<ReportModel>>(context);` get new fetched data as result of `async` function therefore `immutable` widget needs to rebuild itself because it cannot be "changed".

> In object-oriented and functional programming, an immutable object
> (unchangeable object) is an object whose state cannot be modified
> after it is created. ... This is in contrast to a mutable object
> (changeable object), which can be modified after it is created

or am I wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your FutureProvider should be hoisted to a single instantiation, like placed into a global variable outside any build() methods.  This will of course cache the result, so you can set it up for rebuild by having the value depend on other Providers being watch()ed or via FutureProvider.family.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should use `Consumer`, i.e.

```dart
FutureProvider<List<ReportModel>(
  create: (_) => ...,
  child: Consumer<List<ReportModel>(
    builder: (_, reportList, __) {
      return reportList == null ?
        CircularProgressIndicator() :
        ReportWidg(reportList);
    }
  ),
),
```

But in this case you must to refactor your `ReportWidg`.

Comment: In second approach isnt it true that it won't get new async data ? or its hard to tell because it is async...

Comment: After some thinking I came to conclusion that author of second answer is right so approach where `listen: false` is not good idea. So.. only `Consumer` is a common way. At lease I use this always. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Yes. it's normal 
First time `Execute Build` `reportList` is `null` and show `CircularProgressIndicator()` 
Second time `Execute Build` `reportList` has data and show data

If you set `listen: false` , `final reportList = Provider.of<List<ReportModel>>(context, listen: false);` 
You get only one `Execute Build` and the screen will always show `CircularProgressIndicator()`

In working demo simulate 5 seconds network delay so you can see `CircularProgressIndicator()` then show `ListView` 
You can reference https://codetober.com/flutter-provider-examples/ 
code snippet

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Execute Build");
    final reportList = Provider.of<List<ReportModel>>(context);
    print("reportList ${reportList.toString()}");
    if (reportList == null) {
      print("reportList is null");
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    } else if (reportList.isEmpty) {
      return Center(child: Text("Empty"));
    }

    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: reportList.length,
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class ReportModel {
  String title;

  ReportModel({this.title});
}

class ReportsProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  Future<List<ReportModel>> loadReportData(int no) async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () {});
    return Future.value([
      ReportModel(title: "1"),
      ReportModel(title: "2"),
      ReportModel(title: "3")
    ]);
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: ReportsPage(),
    );
  }
}

class ReportsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ReportsPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureProvider<List<ReportModel>>(
        create: (_) async => ReportsProvider().loadReportData(1),
        initialData: null,
        catchError: (_, __) => null,
        child: const ReportWidg());
  }
}

class ReportWidg extends StatelessWidget {
  const ReportWidg();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Execute Build");
    final reportList = Provider.of<List<ReportModel>>(context);
    print("reportList ${reportList.toString()}");
    if (reportList == null) {
      print("reportList is null");
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    } else if (reportList.isEmpty) {
      return Center(child: Text("Empty"));
    }

    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: reportList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Card(
                elevation: 6.0,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 6.0, bottom: 6.0, left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
                  child: Text(reportList[index].title.toString()),
                ));
          }),
    );
  }
}
```